# Identifying a parsing error in a small piece of octave code

Tags: matlab, octave

the code in question, I don't understand why I'm getting the error.

```
function f=f(x)
   f=x-2*exp(-1*x);
end

function Xs = SteffensenRoot(Fun, Xest)
    Xn=Xest;
    i=0;
    while i<100
        Xs = Xn - (Fun(Xn)^2)/(Fun(Xn+Fun(Xn))-Fun(Xn)
        r=(Xs-Xn)/Xn;
        r=abs(r)
        if r<10^-6
           break;
        end
        Xn=Xs;
        i=i+1;
    end

    if i>100
        error('over 100 iterations!')
    end
end

SteffensenRoot(@f, 1)
```

the error I'm getting

```
parse error near line 9 of file /web/com/1447010266_4282/main.m

syntax error

>>> r=(Xs-Xn)/Xn;
^
```

the code is being run through http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/try_matlab.php

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a parenthesis somewhere on the line below:

```
 (Fun(Xn+Fun(Xn))-Fun(Xn)
```

has one more left parenthesis than right parenthesis.